# Compressing data in Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I'm sending data (serialize objects) back and forth over TCP sockets. It gets passed as a ByteString, but and changed to a ByteArray when I use it. What can I use to compress the data before sending?

I've found some information about compressing files, but nothing on raw data. If anyone has ideas it would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two messages `zipped` and `unzipped` but only implemented in String.

If you start with a ByteArray, then you can do

```
someByteArray asString zipped.
```

Comment: Note that I changed that in squeak 4.6 alpha (trunk), it's now just `someByteArray zipped`

Answer (score 2):

You can send binary data as [Fuel](http://rmod.inria.fr/web/software/Fuel) serialisation. Also you can zip and unzip it if you really need compression. But in most cases Fuel does good job

Comment: Use `ZLibWriteStream` for instance. There's also an LZ4 compression package: http://smalltalkhub.com/#!/~marianopeck/LZ4.